# Spring Boot conditional on @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an authentication service that I want to autoconfigure at runtime but that will be mocked up for development and testing. I would like to use the `@ConfigurationProperties` feature to define the necessary parameters, but I also need to be able to only conditionally create the `AuthenticationManager` instances, depending on whether a live service is configured.

The approach I would like to take is to use something like `@ConditionalOnBean(AuthProperties.class)`, but
Spring Boot creates a bean of my `@ConfigurationProperties` class regardless of whether the properties are present. I can apply validation annotations to the fields, but then the context won't start at all if a live service is not configured.

Is there a clean way to make a configuration section conditional on having the properties specified in an `@ConfigurationProperties` class without repeating the property names in `@ConditionalOnProperty`?

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` objects can also be used to specify default values, which would (of course) not be picked up by `@ConditionalOnProperty`. So this still is a very relevant question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use profile of your application-some_profile.properties file and then create your properties bean conditionally like this

```
@Profile("some_profile")
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.selector")

public Class YourConfiguration{
  private property option;
}
```

this way it only gets created conditionally depending which profile you select live or mock.
Than you can either use selected profile for your @Configuration authentication classes for separate approaches or follow with @ConditionalOnBean. That's what profiles are for or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The entire point of the Spring Boot autoconfiguration system is to adapt to the external configuration information without having to specify toggles that just provide redundant information, essentially mini-profiles.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice autoconfiguration.Nothing clean comes to my mind
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.selector")
    @Conditional(YourConfiguration.class)
    public Class YourConfiguration implements Condition {
      private property option;
 @Override
 public boolean matches(ConditionContext context,AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
   //some hardcoded properties checking   
  return (System.getProperty("servicedefault") == null);
 }

    }` not clean but thats the way @Condidional works ,bean will be registered according to condition otherwise fails to register

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I could resolve it with this approach using Spring Boot and Java 8, hope it helps someone:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:integration.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:integration-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "integration")
public class IntegrationProperties {

    private String user;

    private String password;

    private String projectId;

    ....

}
```

**integration.properties**

```
integration.user=User
integration.password=Password
integration.project-id=123
```

**integration-prod.properties**

```
integration.project-id=897
```

Spring Boot will create the bean using the properties file, and for production (using the profile `prod`) it will use the other file and override the `project-id`. The `ignoreResourceNotFound = true` will avoid the FileNotFoundException on startup when you are not using the `prod` profile.